# How do i store multiple data in the same text box from the database? c#

Tags: c#, sql, database, forms, textbox

Hi thanks for viewing my question! I'm having a little trouble getting multiple data from my database. I'm trying to show multiple data in a single text box and it will not let me, of course.

**My code:**

```
string authorised = "notReviewed";
    SundownDatabaseEntities5 dbb = new SundownDatabaseEntities5();
    System.Windows.Forms.Form ff = System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["Login"];
        int idd = Convert.ToInt32(((Login)ff).idTb.Text);
        var getrecordd = dbb.Holidays.Where(a => a.Id == idd).SingleOrDefault();

            if (getrecordd.Authorised == authorised)
            {
            holidaysAuthorisedTb.Text = "Your holiday request (" + getrecordd.Datefrom + " - "+getrecordd.Dateto+") has been sent. Waiting for manager to authorise it...";
            }
```

`FirstOrDefault();` gets the first data it finds but I need them all. How would I go about making it so that it will show multiple data instead of one? Thanks guys!

**e.g. Text box:**

Your holiday request `(" + getrecordd.Datefrom + " - "+getrecordd.Dateto+")` has been sent. Waiting for manager to authorise it...

Your holiday request `(" + getrecordd.Datefrom + " - "+getrecordd.Dateto+")` has been authorised.

Comment: You need to concatenate all the values to a single string in order to use it in a textbox. What do you expect the result should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all records and then use `foreach`.

```
var getrecordds = dbb.Holidays.Where(a => a.Id == idd).ToList();
foreach (var getrecordd in getrecordds) 
{
   if (getrecordd.Authorised == authorised)
   {
        holidaysAuthorisedTb.Text += "Your holiday request (" + getrecordd.Datefrom + " - "+getrecordd.Dateto+") has been sent. Waiting for manager to authorise it...";
   } 
   else 
   {
       holidaysAuthorisedTb.Text += "Your holiday request (" + getrecordd.Datefrom + " - "+getrecordd.Dateto+") has been sent. Waiting for manager to authorise it..."
    }

}
```

Or use `ForEach` method

```
dbb.Holidays.Where(a => a.Id == idd).ForEach ( x => 
{
       if (x.Authorised == authorised)
       {
            holidaysAuthorisedTb.Text += "Your holiday request (" + x.Datefrom + " - "+x.Dateto+") has been sent. Waiting for manager to authorise it...";
       } 
       else 
       {
           holidaysAuthorisedTb.Text += "Your holiday request (" + x.Datefrom + " - "+x.Dateto+") has been sent. Waiting for manager to authorise it..."
       }
});
```